# Create extension postgis gives error: could not open extension control file "/opt/pgpro/std-11/share/extension/postgis.control"

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, postgis

ubuntu server 16.04
postgres Pro standart 11.5 (https://postgrespro.ru)
postgis 2.5

### UPDATE: I found the answer, see below

Posgis is successfully installed in the extensions directory of Postgresql (`usr/share/postgresql/11/extension`), and of course, postgre Pro (which extensions folder is `opt/pgpro/std/-11/share/extension`) cannot find file `postgis.control`.

So, my questions:
1) Can i configure postgresql.conf (config file of postgres pro) to use extensions folder of postgresql?
2) If only solution is installing postgis from binary, then how to set my config file of postgres pro?

I've already tried:
1. Removing postgresql from server.
2. I tried to transfer postgis files, from postgresql extension's folder to postgres pro.

Comment: Not sure what your setup is, but if you use Posrgres Pro's packages, you'll have to use their PostGIS as well.

Comment: I wont to setup postgres Pro with Postgis extension. Documentation postgres pro (https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/11/external-extensions) says, that postgis developed independently. But well-known commands, as well as `apt-get install postgis` and after that sql-command `create extension postgis;` doesn't work, becase postgis installs in postgresql folders, where postgre pro cannot find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone faces the same problem:

```
wget https://postgis.net/stuff/postgis-2.5.4dev.tar.gz
tar xvfz postgis-2.5.4dev.tar.gz
cd postgis-2.5.4dev

sudo apt-get install postgrespro-std-11-dev
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev
sudo apt-get install libproj-dev
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev

sudo ./configure --with-pgconfig=/opt/pgpro/std-11/bin/pg_config
make 
sudo make install
```

And after that connect to your datapase and run `create extension postgis;`.

Answer (score 1):

If Postgres Pro don't provide packages for PostGIS with their fork of PostgreSQL, you will have to build PostGIS from source.

You cannot use the PostGIS packages built for other binaries.